# Dart says Regexp has invalid quantifier, but it works in JavaScript - a bug?

Tags: regex, dart

I have a RegExp:

```
color:\s*+(?!(?:transparent|inherit)(?:;|$))[^@;][^;]*;?
```

Which apparently works over at regex1010.com  http://regex101.com/r/aU1nR4/5

But if you take this expression to Dart, for example if you paste this code:

```
void main() {
    new RegExp(r"color:\s*+(?!(?:transparent|inherit)(?:;|$))[^@;][^;]*;?");
}
```

into http://try.dartlang.org/ you would get:

```
InternalError: uncaught exception: FormatException: Illegal RegExp pattern: color:\s*+(?!(?:transparent|inherit)(?:;|$))[^@;][^;]*;?, SyntaxError: invalid quantifier
$.wrapException@blob:98037409-a6ed-4af3-b17a-97b022530853:218:5
$.throwExpression@blob:98037409-a6ed-4af3-b17a-97b022530853:223:3
$.JSSyntaxRegExp_makeNative@blob:98037409-a6ed-4af3-b17a-97b022530853:411:3
$.JSSyntaxRegExp$@blob:98037409-a6ed-4af3-b17a-97b022530853:399:3
$.main@blob:98037409-a6ed-4af3-b17a-97b022530853:148:3
@blob:98037409-a6ed-4af3-b17a-97b022530853:515:5
@blob:0dee36e0-efe3-40e2-93f5-4fac9fc4fec3:1:61
```

Is there something wrong with my RegExp or maybe possibly a Dart bug somehow?

Comment: Why you added `+` after `\s*`?

Comment: `+` after `\s*` is what causes the exception

Comment: You could look at https://www.debuggex.com/ - if you select JavaScript here it makes a problem but when you select PCRE it is working

Comment: @corgrath how about this http://regex101.com/r/aU1nR4/8 ?

Comment: \s*+ is valid regexp though, right? or is \s*+ not supported in JS?

Comment: `*+` is a [possessive quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html), a feature that's supported in PCRE and Java, but not in JavaScript.  At regex101, you selected `PCRE` as the flavor; if you select `JS` instead, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the below regex instead of your's,

```
^color:(?!@|transparent|inherit| @| transparent| inherit).*;$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aU1nR4/9)

Comment: Even thought the String is marked as "raw" with r""?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I've added possible change to your code as my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Adding more (de facto less) to **Avinash Raj** solution probably this will be better:

```
^color:(?!\s*@|\s*transparent|\s*inherit).*;$
```

because it will be working for any white space characters before transparent, inherit or @ and not just for non whitespaces and one whitepsace

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/eN9cS1/1#javascript)